# Show a real valued holomorphic function on an open and arcwise connected set is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

The question:

Show that a holomorphic function on an open and arcwise connected set $U$ that only attains real values is necessarily constant. Is this still true if we drop the assumption that $U$ is arcwise connected?

I'm pretty new to complex analysis, so I just want some idea of how you would tackle this kind of question. I believe I need to employ the Cauchy Riemann equations somehow. I haven't really been told much about the properties of arcwise connected sets either, so if possible could someone shed some light on those?

Comment: If you write $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ you have $v(x,y)=0$ so by using Cauchy-Riemann equations you get $u(x,y)=c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the **open mapping theorem**, which states that a holomorphic, non-constant function is always an open map(i.e. it sends open subsets of its domain to open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$).

Now, the reals are a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$, so if you have a holomorphic map $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$, where $U$ is open and connected, that map is constant; if it wasn't, $f(U)$ should be open in $\mathbb{C}$.

If we drop the assumption that $U$ is connected, then the map is constant at each component of $U$, but those values may be different for each component.

Comment: This is extremely useful. Do you happen to have any specific examples in mind where the phenomena mentioned in the final sentence occurs? That would be pretty useful to have to hand!

Comment: @user142671 oh, sure. If we use the symbol $U_z$ to mean an open disk with center $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and radius 1, we can see that $U:= U_0 \cup U_3$ has exactly 2 connected components, ($U_0$ and $U_3$) . Then define $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(z)=5$ , $\forall z \in U_0$ and $f(z) = 6$, $\forall z \in  U_3$